# batch file to copy files based on their names

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to come up with a batch file to copy files based on their names.
The filenames are in form `aaa_xx-XX-ccc.txt` where `aaa` and `ccc` do not matter (variable length), but `xx` are 2 character codes. I would like to copy the files into their respective `xx` folders and these folders would also be created by the script.

Here I found something that almost suit my needs:
[Batch file to copy files based on characters in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500242/batch-file-to-copy-files-based-on-characters-in-filename)

> `@echo off
>   setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
>   for %%x in (*.txt) do (
>     set "filename=%%x"
>     set "folder=!filename:~1,2!"
>     if not exist !folder! mkdir !folder!
>     copy "%%x" !folder!
>   )`

But I would like to be looking for the `xx` not only by its position in the filename, but by the specific character (underscore) and position in the filename.

Is there any way to do it?

Update - example:
I have the following files in a single folder:

My-Project_ar-SA-2016114-12h33m10s.txt

My-Project_cs-CZ-2016114-12h33m8s.text

My-Project_da-DK-2016114-12h33m10s.txt

The "template" for the filenames is "[project-name]_[language-CODE]-[dateAndTime].txt

And I want to copy the first file into a different location\ar folder (for example "C:\Output\ar"), the second file into "C:\Output\cs" etc.

Comment: An detailled example of what you really need will be good !

Comment: Ok, I will try to use an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*_*-*-*.txt" '
  ) DO (
 FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%c IN ("%%a") DO (
  FOR /f "tokens=1,2*delims=-" %%q IN ("%%d") DO (
   ECHO(COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%q\"
  )
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

The required COPY commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(COPY` to `COPY` to actually copy the files. Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file copied`)

It isn't clear whether you want the destination directory to be `xx` or `XX`. This is set up for `xx` for `XX` use `%%r` in place of `%%q` in the `copy` line.

Read the directory for files only using the mask *_*-*-*.txt into `%%a`

Remove the leading characters up to the underscore by tokenising using `_` and selecting `%%d`, the trailing portion

re-tokenise `%%d` on `-`. first token to `%%q`, second to `%%r`

Mix and match to create the `copy` command.

Note that your second filename, ...CZ... is a `.text` filename, not a `.txt`

Comment: Hello, is there any solution if I want both the "xx-XX" for the destination directory? I tried to modify the copy command to:
COPY "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%q\-\%%r\"
but it keeps giving me wrong paths.

Answer (score 0):

According that all `.txt`files in the directory you're running the `BAT` are to be copied and the template is stricly what you described.

Here is an idea to do it :

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=1,2,3* delims=_-" %%a in ('dir *.txt /b/a-d') do echo copy "%%a%%b%%c%%d" "c:\output\%%c"
```

Remove the `echo` before the `copy` if the Output is OK